# Why using Kotlin "by" over anonymous subclass?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm currently watching this [video](https://youtu.be/fPzxfeDJDzY?t=16m50s) from the Google I/O 2017 and came across the `by` feature of Kotlin.

There is the following example to avoid to implement every single method of an interface when you actually care of only one of them.

With `by` implementation (from the video):

```
class MyListener : TransitionListener by EmptyTransitionListener {
    override fun onTransitionStart(transition: Transition) {
    }
}

object EmptyTransitionListener : TransitionListener {
    override fun onTransitionEnd(transition: Transition) {}
    override fun onTransitionResume(transition: Transition) {}
    override fun onTransitionPause(transition: Transition) {}
    override fun onTransitionCancel(transition: Transition) {}
    override fun onTransitionStart(transition: Transition) {}
}

window.sharedElementEnterTransition.addListener(MyListener())
```

Without `by` implementation (as I'm used to do):

```
open class EmptyTransitionListener : TransitionListener {
    override fun onTransitionEnd(transition: Transition) {}
    override fun onTransitionResume(transition: Transition) {}
    override fun onTransitionPause(transition: Transition) {}
    override fun onTransitionCancel(transition: Transition) {}
    override fun onTransitionStart(transition: Transition) {}
}

window.sharedElementEnterTransition.addListener(object: EmptyTransitionListener() {
            override fun onTransitionStart(transition: Transition) {
            }
        })
```

What are the advantages of one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Principle: Composition > Inheritance

It simply follows the principle of ["Composition over inheritance"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

> Composition over inheritance (or composite reuse principle) in object-oriented programming (OOP) is the principle that classes should achieve polymorphic behavior and code reuse by their composition (*by containing instances of other classes that implement the desired functionality*) rather than inheritance from a base or parent class. This is an often-stated **principle of OOP** [...].

#### Kotlin Delegation `by`

That's exactly what `by` is, Kotlin's keyword for applying [class delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html).

> The **Delegation pattern** has proven to be a good alternative to implementation inheritance, and Kotlin supports it natively requiring zero boilerplate code.

#### Delegation Pattern

Also, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern:

> In software engineering, the delegation pattern is an object-oriented design pattern that allows object composition to achieve the same code reuse as inheritance. [...]

#### Further reading

Follow this [stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53354/8073652) fo further information.

Answer (score 3):

With `by`, you can *reuse* the same implementation for multiple class.

```
class MyListener : TransitionListener by EmptyTransitionListener {
    override fun onTransitionStart(transition: Transition) {
        Log.d("MyListener", "Hi from MyListener!")
    }
}

class MySecondListener : TransitionListener by EmptyTransitionListener {
    override fun onTransitionStart(transition: Transition) {
        Log.d("MySecondListener ", "Hi from MySecondListener!")
    }
}

object EmptyTransitionListener : TransitionListener {
    override fun onTransitionEnd(transition: Transition) {}
    override fun onTransitionResume(transition: Transition) {}
    override fun onTransitionPause(transition: Transition) {}
    override fun onTransitionCancel(transition: Transition) {}
    override fun onTransitionStart(transition: Transition) {}
}

window.sharedElementEnterTransition.addListener(MyListener())
```